# Memory leak - release and delete

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com, visual-c++-6, delete-operator

```
IFSUPCUTILSize* size = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UTILSize, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFSUPCUTILSize,    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&size));
            
if (size != NULL){
size->Release();
size = NULL;
}
delete size;
```

Do I need "delete size" in the code above?
If I include "delete size", will I have a memory leak because I did not use New?
Or is there a New inside the call to `CoCreateInstance`.
I built this with VC++ 6.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to a more recent version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

COM interfaces are reference counted.  `CoCreateInstance()` returns an interface pointer to a COM object whose reference count has already been incremented.  Calling `Release()` decrements the reference count.  When the reference count falls to zero, the COM object frees itself automatically.  DO NOT call `delete` on a COM interface pointer!  Always use `Release()` only.

Comment: Thanks. Good education for me. OP

Answer (score 4):

From a C++ perspective, what you're doing is fine.  Calling delete on a null pointer is a no-op.  However, it's unnecessary.

From a VC++6 perspective, I cannot say, it's notoriously non-compliant.  I can't imagine why it might be a problem though.  But again, it's certainly unnecessary.

**Definitely do not call delete on this pointer before it's set to NULL.**  You did not allocate with new, so don't call delete.  Resource management here is taken care of by the COM functions.

Answer (score 1):

Never try to use `delete` to release COM servers implemented by another module (that's your case).

1. You don't always know if that server is written in C++. Doing `delete` on a non-C++ object is undefined behavior.
2. Even if the server is written in C++, you don't know on which heap it was allocated and whether `delete` will deallocate memory properly or trigger undefined behavior.
3. You call `delete` on an interface pointer that is declared as not having a virtual destructor - that's undefined behavior.
4. You don' always know if you've been served a real object or a proxy. Doing `delete` on a proxy is undefined behavior.
5. Once you called `Release()` the object may have already self-deleted and doing `delete` again is undefined behavior.
6. Some third party might have taken ownership of the object -for example, some global pointer instance might have  been set to your object. If you `delete` those other pointers will become dangling and that will likely cause undefined behavior later.

Bottom line: don't use `delete` in this case ever. Call `Release()` to release ownership of the object and that will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> If I include "delete size", will I have a memory leak because I did not use New.

You generally won't get a memory leak by calling `delete`.  You **can** and many times **will** get memory corruption.  The two are very different:  a memory leak means that your program holds onto memory that it doesn't actually use, over time the program might crash if the leaked memory continues to grow; memory corruption means that you somehow clobbered important bookkeeping structures in memory, and likely will crash very soon (at least you ought to hope for a crash, the alternative is worse).  [One very common cause of memory corruption is deallocating memory with the wrong routine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx), especially on Windows (it's something of a tradition to redefine `malloc` and `free` on UNIX, so UNIX systems [often go out of their way to make sure it's possible to do that](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/307)).

> Or is there a New inside the call to CoCreateInstance

Whatever's inside `CoCreateInstance` should be handled by `Release()`.  At the very least, you should never deallocate memory just because you have a pointer.  You need to know how they memory was allocated in order to deallocate it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that size->Release() is releasing OS resources (file handles etc). Therefor put the delete size immediately after before setting size to null.

Comment: He didn't allocate with new, he should not call delete on it.

Comment: I inherited the code. I check the rest of the code. Pointers are released and set to null in the next line.  I added the delete myself out of ignorance.  I guess there is no harm for  a compliant compiler. But MS, I better remove it.  I agree that I don't need to delete if I don't have a New. Thanks. This forum is great.